# How can I change "NA" to other characters?

Tags: r, replace, na

I have the following dataset:

```
structure(list(time = c("set. 2022", "oct. 2022", "nov. 2022", 
"des. 2022", "gen. 2023", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Unió Europea` = c(5.7, 
3.7, 2.7, -0.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Zona Euro` = c(5.1, 
3.3, 2.7, -1.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Espanya = c(3.8, 2.4, 
-1.3, 1.3, -0.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), França = c(1.6, -2.6, 
0.4, 1.6, -2.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Itàlia = c(-0.5, -1.7, 
-3.4, 0.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I want to change all "NA" values to "No disponible" or "nd". I tried `replace_na(df, "no disponible")` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure? That makes all numeric columns coerced into character types.

Comment: That's also an issue... So the thing is that I'm doing a table with `kable` in RMarkdown but I don't want the NAs values to appear as such but "No disponible".

Comment: You can set `options(knitr.kable.NA = "no disponible")` before creating a `kable`.

Comment: @DarrenTsai its possible to print the NA as anything while maintaining the class to be numeric. Although since OP wants to use `kable`, its advisable to use the option you gave

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work.

```
library(dplyr)

df2<-df%>%mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), "nd"))
```